# Get the segmentation mask for the bounded polygon

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to create the segmentation mask for each red color boundary. Input image has 4 polygons with a red color boundary. I want to mark each polygon segment with different colors as shown in the output. Please help me with this.

Input Image
[image: Input image]

Output Image
[image: Output Image]

Comment: "*I am trying to...*" can you please post what have you tried so far in terms of code: [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

1. take red channel only. consider as single-channel grayscale/binary.
2. invert. areas become white. borders become black.
3. **connected components labeling** (of the white areas). `connectedComponents` is the API

To paint a picture where each area has a color, use numpy operations (mask indexing, assignment) to construct that picture from the labels map returned by `connectedComponents`.

Comment: could you help me with the codes

Comment: do you have code that needs help?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply scan through the image and do the following:

1. execute [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) with a unique (non-red color) every time you find a black pixel
2. replace red border with the same color if needed
3. repeat

[image]